# Loop through a json array: Read first line and loop from the second line

Tags: jquery

With an array like mine below, how can I read the values of only the first line and the loop through the other from the second line onward? I've included comments in the code to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PHP, jQuery search demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/dev/ajax/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $(".errCheck").click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:  "test_errors.php",
                dataType:"json",
                cache:false,

                success: function(data){
                //if 1st line of array: success == True How can I do this?
                //Redirect
                //else
                $('#errors div').empty();
                $.each(data, function (loc, msg) {//start from the second array value, in this case errOne
                $(loc).html(msg);
                });              

              },

            });    

        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="errors">
<div id="errOne"></div>
<div id="errTwo"></div>
<div id="errThree"></div>
</div> 
<input type="submit" class="errCheck" value="Check">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My test error messages file:

```
<?php

$errors['success'] = "false";
$errors['#errOne'] = "Enter a valid username";
$errors['#errTwo'] = "Enter a valid email";
$errors['#errThree'] = "Enter a valid password";

echo json_encode($errors);

?>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the returned json?

Comment: {"success":"false","#errOne":"Enter a valid username","#errTwo":"Enter a valid email","#errThree":"Enter a valid password"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use shift() to return the first element in an array and remove it from the array</strike>

<strike>var error = data.shift();</strike>

<strike>So, var error will be your check and data can then be used in you $.each()</strike>

@Joseph Silber - Congratulations on spotting my deliberate mistake above ;-P

Use

```
delete myObject.property; // or myObject[property]
```

As per [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

**EDIT** I guess this is now the same as another answer but I felt like I might as well write the code in...

And use a proper boolean as stated elsewhere

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data.success == false) {
    delete data.success;
    $.each(data,function(loc, msg){
      $(loc).html(msg);
    })
  } else {
    // passed validation code
  }
}
```

---

Although I'd prefer to arrange the Json like this

```
{
  success: false,
  errors: [
    {fieldKey: 'string'},
    {fieldKey: 'string'}
  ]
}
```

Etc.

Comment: -1 `.shift` is a method on the Array prototype. It won't work on objects (object properties have no order).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value of `data.success` is a string of either `true` or `false`, use this:

```
if ( data.success == 'true' ) {
    window.location = 'http://new_url.com';
    return;
}

delete data.success;
// Now just run the loop
```

Ideally though, you should store a real Boolean in `success`. So in your PHP code you should use:

```
$errors['success'] = false;
// or
$errors['success'] = true;
```

Then, in your JavaScript, you would check it as a real Boolean:

```
if ( data.success ) {
    // redirect...
}
```

Comment: `$errors['success'] = "false";`, so this will always evaluate to true. he should use a `false` literal in PHP.

Comment: @Esailija - I missed that. Though I can't imagine why the OP won't use a real Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a counter as there is no index on the object, just the key :

```
$(function() {
    $(".errCheck").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test_errors.php",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) document.location.href = 'http://google.com';
                $('#errors div').empty();
                $.each(data, function(loc, msg) {
                    $(loc).html(msg);
                });
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: This in indeterministic because the loop order is not defined for objects.

Comment: @pimvdb - Not only that, but I did'nt get the question at all ?

Comment: $.each(data, function(loc, msg) {//How can I start at [1] here and not [0] Eg: for (i=1; i<blah; i++)